# How to compose a nested function g=fn(...(f3(f2(f1()))...) from a list of functions [f1, f2, f3,...fn]

Tags: python

## Question

Is there a readily available Pythonic way to compose a multiple nested function g = f3(f2(f1())) from a list of functions [f1, f2, f3] where there are more functions in a list.

If there are a few, I may do:

```
g = lambda x: f3(f2(f1(x)))
```

However when I have dozens of functions e.g layers in a deep neural network, it is un-manageable. Prefer not creating another function to compose g but finding an available way.

---

## Update

Based on the answer from @Chris. For sequential neural network layers `[ batchnorm, matmul, activation, softmaxloss ]`, each of which has a `forward(X)` method to calculate its output to the next layer, the loss function L and loss would be:

```
L = reduce(lambda f, g: lambda X: g(f(X)),  [ layer.forward for layer in layers ] )   # Loss function
network_loss = L(X)
```

Comment: Why don't you simply apply the functions in a loop?

Comment: You shouldn't give the `.forward` methods of layers, but rather the layers themselves, their `__call__` methods will then implicitly be used, including a call to `.forward` but also including registered hooks if there are any, see https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/any-different-between-model-input-and-model-forward-input/3690/2

Comment: @paime, you misunderstood the question in the Pytorch forum. The person who asked the question implemented class MyModel(nn.Module) which has forward method defined as per the nn.Model parent class which implements __call__ method. This has nothing to do with Pytorch model class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way using `functools.reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

f1 = lambda x: x+1
f2 = lambda x: x*2
f3 = lambda x: x+3
funcs = [f1, f2, f3]

g = reduce(lambda f, g: lambda x: g(f(x)), funcs)
```

Output:

```
g(1)==7 # ((1+1) * 2) + 3
g(2)==9 # ((2+1) * 2) + 3
```

Insight:

`functools.reduce` will chain its second argument (`funcs` here) according to its first argument (`lambda` here).

That being said, it will start chaining `f1` and `f2` as `f_21(x) = f2(f1(x))`, then `f3` and `f_21` as `f3(f_21(x))` which becomes `g(x)`.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the `reduce` function and its arguments a little bit?

Comment: @codeforester `reduce` will chain its second argument (`funcs` here) as stated in its first argument (`lambda` here). That being said, it will start chaining `f1` and `f2` as `f_21(x) = f2(f1(x))`, then `f3` and `f_21` as `f3(f_21(x))` which becomes `g(x)`.

Comment: Thanks. Mind adding it to the answer?

Answer (score 3):

One problem with the `reduce`-baed approach is that you introduce O(n) additional function calls.  An alternative is to define a *single* function that remembers the functions to compose; when called, it simply calls each function in sequence on the given argument.

```
def compose(*args):
    """compose(f1, f2, ..., fn) == lambda x: fn(...(f2(f1(x))...)"""

    def _(x):
        result = x
        for f in args:
            result = f(result)
        return result
    return _
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight. What is your view on the ```compose``` module (https://pypi.org/project/compose/) suggested by @Stuart Berg, if I may ask.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement it yourself, but you could also try [a module named `compose`](https://github.com/mentalisttraceur/python-compose) which implements this, written by @mtraceur.  It takes care to handle various details, such as correct function signature forwarding.

```
pip install compose
```

```py
from compose import compose

def doubled(x):
    return 2*x

octupled = compose(doubled, doubled, doubled)

print(octupled(1))
# 8
```